# Facebook Invitation with new API (v2.0)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

As we know, in the new version of Facebook API there are a lot of restrictions, especially getting the list of friends who are not app users. And because of this, we cannot invite friends to the app because they are not app users and we can't get their `uid`.

And as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m), the only way to get friend list is `/me/taggable_friends` or `/me/invitable_friends`, but in this case Facebook will reject this permission if we will use those for other purposes (like for invitation, etc...).

So what do you think about this? What solution do you have for telling to the friends about the app?
I'm thinking to show a `FBWebDialog` to post an "invitation text" on friend's wall, but I can't find the way to show the right one, where user can select his friend itself. Is that possible at all?

Comment: AFAIK all you can do now is tag people in a post to your own wall if they are not already a user of the app.

Comment: the only non-spammy way to tell your friends about the app is to let users post something about it on their own wall.

Comment: Why don't you use the request dialog? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.0

Comment: Because my application isn't a game.

Comment: Use the share or send/message dialog. As described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq